# Curve25519 ECDH in WebCrypto

Tags: javascript, cryptography, webcrypto-api

I have read this [document](https://www.w3.org/2012/webcrypto/WebCryptoCurve25519/Curve25519-WebCrypto.html) to generate keys pair via **ECDH-CURVE25519** algorithom. But JS error(**DOMException: Algorithm: Unrecognized name**) is thrown when I spcified **ECDH-CURVE25519** as algorithom name in **window.crypto.subtle.generateKey**.

```
    window.crypto.subtle.generateKey(
    {
        name: "ECDH-CURVE25519"
    },
    true, 
    ["deriveKey", "deriveBits"] 
)
.then(function(key){
    console.log(key);
   pk = key.publicKey;
    vk = key.privateKey;
})
.catch(function(err){
    console.error(err);
});
```

Comment: That's nice. Seriously, what error and what is your question? Note: didn't vote down.

Comment: The document you pointed to read: "First Draft", so it's unlikely that any browser vendor would implement it, as the API could change afterwards.

Comment: Updates:  Chromium now appears to have a runtime flag called `WebCryptoCurve25519`:  https://chromestatus.com/feature/4913922408710144  NodeJS has vendor prefix `NODE-ED25519`.  WebKit/Safari has apparently already implemented the feature (see link from Chrome status page).  That leaves Firefox, which only has a "positive position" and zero code.  Maybe sometime in the near future we'll be able to use [safe curves](https://safecurves.cr.yp.to/) in web browsers that don't have likely backdoors so that the NSA can't do little "looksie-peeksies" (aka remote exploits).

Comment: WebCrypto status for all browsers is at: https://github.com/WICG/webcrypto-secure-curves/issues/20

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Curve25519 is not supported by WebCryptographyApi.

Instead you can use `P-256` (secp256r1), `P-384`(secp386r1) and `P-521`(secp521r1). See https://www.w3.org/TR/WebCryptoAPI/#dfn-EcKeyGenParams

The code should be like this

```
window.crypto.subtle.generateKey(
    {
        name: "ECDH",
        namedCurve: "P-256", // "P-256", "P-384", or "P-521"
    },
    true, 
    ["deriveKey", "deriveBits"] 
)
.then(function(key){
   console.log(key);
   pk = key.publicKey;
   vk = key.privateKey;
})
.catch(function(err){
    console.error(err);
});
```